# Django + HTML: Why does my if condition in my template fail even thought I havent submitted interest?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Django + HTML:  Why does my if condition in my template fail even thought I havent submitted interest?

As you can see from my views.py i have already indicated that if you have submitted interest, you will get the message that you have submitted the interest, otherwise the button 'submit interest' will be shown. Why does it not work then?

views.py

```
def detail_blog_view(request, slug):

    context = {}
#need to import a package get_object_or_404. return object or throw 404
    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    total_likes = blog_post.total_likes()
    liked = False
    if blog_post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        liked = True
    context['liked'] = liked
    context['blog_post'] = blog_post
    context['total_likes'] = total_likes
    account = Account.objects.all()
    context['account'] = account
    #when post does not belong to me
    if blog_post.author != request.user:
        submittedinterest = False
        if blog_post.author.interestsender.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            submittedinterest = True
        context['submittedinterest'] = submittedinterest
    #when the post belongs to me
    else:
        pass 
    
    return render(request, 'HomeFeed/detail_blog.html', context)
```

template

```
{% if submittedinterest %}
     <a href="{% url 'HomeFeed:submitinterest' blog_post.slug %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Collaborate!</button></a>
      {% else %}
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
      <p class="text-center">You have submitted your interest.</p>
    </div>
      {% endif %}
```

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
 chief_title                    = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
 body                   = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
 likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='blog_posts', blank=True)
 author                     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 slug                   = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)

class Interest(models.Model):
   interestsender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='interestsender', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   interestreceiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='interestreceiver', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   blog_post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with your if condition in the view

```
if blog_post.author != request.user:
    submittedinterest = False
    if blog_post.author.interestsender.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        submittedinterest = True
    context['submittedinterest'] = submittedinterest
#when the post belongs to me
else:
    pass  //this statement
```

In the outer if condition, you are not setting any value to the `context['submittedinterest']` which means it will not exist in the context. Hence in the template when you do `{% if submittedinterest %}` it will always evaluate to false if the blog post belongs to you. To fix this you need to do `context['submittedinterest'] = False` in the outer else condition.
The question isn't very clear regarding where exactly the error is occuring, and I cannot comment so I clarified what I think the error could be. If you can clarify more!

Comment: Hi bro thanks for the input, do let me know what other codes you require but basically, for every blog post, you can "submit interest" and if you have already submitted your interest, the submit interest button should change to this text: You have submitted your interest

Comment: the logic here is, if the blog post dont belong to me, then all these `    submittedinterest = False
    if blog_post.author.interestsender.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        submittedinterest = True
    context['submittedinterest'] = submittedinterest' will happen

Comment: why would i need context['submittedinterest'] = False in the outer else condition, in the outer else condition i wont even need this cause the post belongs to me and theres no reason to submit interest

Comment: In this if condition `if blog_post.author.interestsender.filter(id=request.user.id).exists()` when you reverse lookup interestsender and filter using the id, it will filter with the id of the Interest object not the interestsender field. What you should be doing is `if blog_post.author.interestreceiver.filter(interestsender__id=request.user.id).exists()`. This will get you if there exists any Interest object for that specific post by the signed in user.

Comment: If the post belongs to you, the code goes to the outer else condition and hence there is no key `submittedinterest` in the context you are passing to the template.So inside your template, your `{% if submittedinterest %}` condition will evaluate to false and the `{% else %}` condition will render. That is why you will be seeing that you have submitted interest rendered on your own blogpost.

Comment: no bro my own blogpost is fine, its when I look at other people's blogpost. My own blog post dont even have that button or the message

Comment: i tried your code here but it didnt work :( `if blog_post.author.interestreceiver.filter(interestsender__id=request.user.id).exists()`

Comment: Try `Interest.objects.filter(blog_post=blog_post, interestreceiver=blog_post.author, interestsender=request.user).exists()`. Also try running this in shell and see if you are getting the correct results.

Comment: yea bro sorry man it still doesnt work. If you dont believe you can try it on your laptop. I even created a new view and linked it to a new html page to try but didnt work as well